# What is the name of the soundtrack when Madara was absorbing chakra from Hashirama?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the soundtrack when Madara was absorbing chakra from Hashirama?

It happened on Naruto Shippuden episode 391 Madara Uchiha Rises.

And in this [YouTube video 3:23 ~ 3:58](https://youtu.be/I90Y3Nb9i-Q?t=203).

Answer (score 1):

Found. It's called "The Allied Shinobi" and should be a part of Naruto Shippuden OST 3.

Below is a sample of the song, not the full thing, and you should notice the same parts as from your link https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=7&v=G_H7hMRc-Nc&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I do not know the name of the song, but I do have [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yt4zL89X8HU) to where you can listen to it. This was googled and I do not think there is an actual soundtrack to the song but the link provided is very much the song you have been looking for

Comment: The BGM he's asking for isn't specific to Madara and Hashirama, but part of the general soundtrack.

Comment: Yes, this is a soundtrack specific to the request...